# Create a new tag for questions related to core JavaScript

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, tag-creation

Being a core JavaScript programmer I have added the JavaScript tag to my favorites so that I may answer questions that I know I can answer well.

However most of the questions being tagged as JavaScript questions have little or nothing to do with JavaScript itself. Hence I find myself hunting for questions related to JavaScript.

For example almost every question tagged as jQuery is also tagged as JavaScript. I'm not a jQuery expert. I hardly know anything about jQuery. Yet every second question tagged as JavaScript is related to jQuery.

The same goes for questions which are more concerned with HTML or CSS. Then there are questions related to ASP.NET and JavaScript GTK which pop up (but not so frequently).

A recent trend is to tag questions related to MVC frameworks like AngularJS as a JavaScript question. Not to mention questions related to Ender, node.js, CommonJS, etc.

With the JavaScript tag being used so nonchalantly it becomes difficult to hunt for questions related to the JavaScript language itself, and I often find myself checking in the site for a few seconds to see whether there's a question I may answer well and then checking out again.

JavaScript is a very popular language. It's used almost everywhere. It's not a surprise that there are so many questions tagged as JavaScript which are not really concerned with JavaScript itself.

So I suggest creating a new tag - perhaps called `core-javascript` or `javascript-language` which targets questions specifically geared towards the language itself.

Comment: I've two comments. First: it seems that JavaScript frameworks like JQuery etc are here to stay, and are likely to become an increasingly important part of web development. Limiting yourself to just "core JavaScript" is probably not a good idea in the long run. Second: if you really do want to limit your SO experience to only core JavaScript, you can always add JQuery etc to your "ignored" tags, and omit them from searches as @Doorknob describes. We don't need a whole new tag just for the benefit of the few people who have an aversion to JavaScript frameworks.

Comment: Old question, but I support this request from a different perspective. I often ask questions where I want a core JavaScript solution, and I want to make it clear that jQuery is _not_ an answer. Saying so in the question doesn’t always seem to work. As regards the above comment, I do have jQuery knowledge, but I don’t think you’re going to progress your own JavaScript expertise by falling back to a particular library which, by design, has its own peculiarities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't just create a tag. It is created when it is added to a question. If you don't have enough rep, then you can ask a question about this, link to it, and then someone with enough rep will add the tag and it will be created.

Keep in mind that if not enough questions use it, it may be removed.

About jQuery: just search `[javascript] -[jquery]` for questions tagged JavaScript but not jQuery.  Same with all the other "JavaScript related" tags.